# Give an example of a converging sequence in which the configurations $x^{(n)}$ (for $n=1,2,...$) are all distinct

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

> Let $X := Σ^{\mathbb N}$ be the set of all configurations over an alphabet $Σ$. Every word $w = w_1w_2 · · · w_n ∈ Σ^∗$ defines a subset of $X$ by
> $C(w) := \{x ∈ X : x_1x_2 · · · x_n = w_1w_2 · · · w_n\}$.
> This is called the cylinder set with base $w$ in $X$. Observe that $C(λ) = X$.

> (a) Verify that the cylinder sets in $X$ form a basis for a topology on $X$.

> (b) Let us equip $X$ with the topology generated by the cylinder sets.
> Verify that every cylinder set is clopen (i.e., both open and closed) in $X$.

> (c)  Give an example of a converging sequence in which the configurations $x^{(n)}$ (for $n=1,2,...$) are all distinct. Give also an example of a non-converging sequence in which the
> configurations $x^{(n)}$
> (for $n = 1, 2, . . .$) are all distinct.

My attempts:

(a) I managed to prove the 2 properties of a basis for a topolgy.

(b) By definition, every cylinder set is open, so I only need to show it is also closed. So I showed that $X - \{B(w)\}$ is open by showing that it is a union of open cylinder sets.

(c) I can't think of such examples. Can you please give me some for converging and non-converging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $x^{(n)}$ over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ as follows for $k,n \in \Bbb N$:

$$x^{(n)}_k = \begin{cases} 1 & k < n\\
                             0& k \ge n\end{cases}$$

This converges to $x = 11\ldots \in \Sigma^{\Bbb N}$. Here all terms are distinct.

A non-converging one:

$$x^{(n)}_k = \begin{cases} 0 & k+n \text{ even}\\
                            1 & k+n \text{ odd} \end{cases}$$

There the coordinate sequences never stabilise. See your previous questions on this plus the answers.